# How do I add text on a video like PayPal's?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, paypal

In PayPal they have the tagline "You Make it, We'll it pay" on top of a video with a small play button near at the corner. When you click on this play button a video will start playing causing the dark overlay which once layered the video when it wasn't in play, to smoothly vanish with the tagline still there. How is this done? Can you provide examples please, I think the effect is pretty neat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/d939e/11/)

Here is the example to show a full screen video from `<video>` tag using only css for fullscreen stuff and further as required text over over the image by using `position: absolute`

css

```
.videoInsert {
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
h2 span { 
   color: white; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* fallback color */
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   padding: 10px;
    z-index: 999999999999;
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <video class="videoInsert">
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
<h2><span>A nice office video:<br />Yes it is!</span></h2>
```